# Xcode address label in view

Tags: xcode10

I have positioned two labels in a view. I connected the view to IBOutlet. Now I want to address one of the labels and change the text color. Is this possible without creating any more IBOutlets for the labels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the subviews of your view:

```
let labels: [UILabel] = myView.subviews as! [UILabel]
```

To know which label is which, without creating IBOutlets, you can add a `tag` property in your storyboard, in the **Attributes inspector**:

[image: Attributes inspector]

In the **View** section, set the tag to an integer to make each label unique:

[image: Tag]

For example, you could set the tag of the first label to 1, and the tag of the second one to 2.

To change the text of the first label:

```
if let firstLabel = labels.first(where: { $0.tag == 1}) {
    firstLabel.text = "Hello World!"
}
```